# Evaluating function taken as input

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

Consider this toy example:

```
myDerivative[f_, x_] := D[f, {x, 2}]
```

This defines a function `myDerivative` that takes in a function `f` and a variable `x` and takes the second derivative of `f`, i.e. it returns $f''$. This works as expected:

```
myDerivative[x^2, x]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

However, consider a slightly different version:

```
myDerivative2[f_, x_] := D[f[x^2], {x, 2}]
```

The difference here is that before differentiation, the function `f` is composed with `x^2`. This particular composition here is irrelevant, it's just to highlight that I have to somehow evaluate the function `f` with my function, I can't just leave as `f` like before. This no longer works:

```
myDerivative2[x^2, x]
```

> ```
> 2[x^2] + 2 x Derivative[1][(2 x)][x^2] + 2 Derivative[1][(x^2)][x^2] + 2 x (Derivative[1][(2 x)][x^2] + 2 x ((x^2)^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x^2])
> ```

It does, however, work if I supply a pure function, or just a head:

```
myDerivative2[#^2 &, x]
myDerivative2[Sin, x]
```

> ```
> 12 x^2
> 2 Cos[x^2] - 4 x^2 Sin[x^2]
> ```

How can I define `myDerivative2` such that `myDerivative[x^2, x]` works as expected, without resorting to inputting a pure function? Google surprisingly didn't provide an answer to this (maybe I don't know the right terms), all that I could find used pure functions like `#^2&` or `Sin` (just the head).

Comment: Try writing it as `myDerivative2[f_, x_] := D[Function[x, f][x^2], {x, 2}]`

Comment: I guess it was really that simple... Thank you, that works perfectly

Comment: @Bob, "The difference here is that before differentiation, the function `f` is composed with `x^2`."